# window snap feature: is there any shortcut to switch between snapped window

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

while using windows snap feature,using second option (thick and thin one)  many time it happens that I want to put a specific app in thin window (i.e. on right side ) and other app in thick window but it happens reverse by me and then have to reset and do the placement again.

so I was looking for any windows keyboard shortcut/ feature which do it instantly the position of snapped window. right one on left and left one on right side.

[image: window 11 snap feature]

Comment: you are familiar with winkey + arrowkeys? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241